# Filter and visualize select keys and values from a pandas table

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to only show the interested keys and their associated values. Also, None means N/A. I would also like to the keys, like capitalize them or instead of lastUpdateEt, make it Last Updated at or instead of total, make it Total Tested.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


state = input("Enter two character state code eg: NY, CA: ")
url = "https://covidtracking.com/api/states?state={}".format(state)

result = requests.get(url)
dataobj = result.json()

# Only intersted in showing these keys and their associated values:
# interested_keys['state','positive','grade','negative','pending','hospitalized','death','total','lastUpdateEt']


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataobj, orient='index',columns=['Values'])
df
```

[image: Current Output:]

Comment: `df.loc[df.index.isin(interested_keys)]`

Comment: `df.loc[interested_keys]`

Comment: you can directly do : `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dataobj, orient='index',columns=['Values']).loc[interested_keys]`

Comment: @anky_91 Is there a way format the keys, like capitalize them or instead of lastUpdateEt, make it Last Updated at or instead of total, make it Total Tested.